# how use an array in string content android?

Tags: android, xml, arraylist, hashmap

i have a xml file and get data from this file and save it in arraylist

xml file :

```
    <head>33</head>
   <link>http://hamrahtest.ir/testcenterv13.apk</link>
</group>
<group>

    <head>355</head>
   <link>http://hamrahtest.ir/testcenterv5555.apk</link>
</group>
```

```java
 protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_GROUPS);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
             Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

            map.put(KEY_HEAD, parser.getValue(e, KEY_HEAD));
            map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }
        Log.d("tagname",songsList.get(1).get(KEY_HEAD).toString());

     }
```

Under this code i have a line :

```java
private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] {" page1","page2"};
```

how i can insert KEY_HEAD valuse to CONTENT Instead {" page1","page2"} ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of `HashMap` keys using `Set<String>` and the convert `Set<String>` to `String[]` using [toArray(T[] a)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143060/how-use-an-array-in-string-content-android)

```
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
String[] CONTENT = new String[keys .size()];
keys.toArray(CONTENT);
```